# Curious about Format function with Phone Number

Tags: c#

UPDATE (SOLVED): https://dotnetfiddle.net/6GEJyO

---

I used the following code to format a phone number in a loop with various formats:

```
string PhoneNumber = "9998675309"
String.Format("{0:" + formatString + "}", Convert.ToDouble(PhoneNumber))
```

I need to format phone numbers two slightly different ways. One came out as I expected and the other did not.

So, curious, I decided to do a quick console app and see all of the different phone number formatting possibilities I could think of. Here is that result:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/PfKlZfM.png]

My question is this: Why do some of those come out formatted the way that they seem like they should and others do not? Are there escape characters that are needed for some of them?

Comment: It's a small thing but you really ought to be using a `long` rather than a `double` to store the number before formatting.

Comment: Wouldnt either work if I also do some validation to make sure that it is 1) exactly 10 characters long and 2) contains only digits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `"."` has a special meaning in a format string. Determines the location of the decimal separator in the result string. So you have to escape the `"."`:

```
string formatString = "###-###\\.####";
```

Some examples of the usage of the `"."` in format strings:

```
// the result is "3.40"
(3.4).ToString("#.00", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))

// the result is "3,142"
(3.141592).ToString("#.000", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-NL"))
```

Comment: I did this on a cool little dot net fiddle and it worked! Very cool to know, thank you. https://dotnetfiddle.net/6GEJyO

Comment: PS - worth noting. Before I posted I had tried a quick test at escaping the periods with ONE backslash instead of the TWO that you answered with. Maybe that will help someone else.